# Displaying cf post formats with oembed

Tags: post-formats, embed, oembed, audio, video-player

Currently using CF Post Formats ( http://alexking.org/blog/2011/10/25/wordpress-post-formats-admin-ui ) and using the following code to automatically embed a URL that has been input into the 'Audio' or 'Video' custom field:

```
<?php echo wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_audio_embed', true) ); ?>
```

However, if oembed does not support the service (Eg. Spotify) and the user inputs the full embed code, it does not echo out anything.

How could I get around this so that if the user inserts code starting with something like:

```
<iframe...
```

then it won't use Oembed and instead it will display normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php
if (strstr($audio, '<iframe')) {
echo $audio;
} else {
echo wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_audio_embed', true) );
}
?>`

Of course, this would require that you get the custom field with the audio embed code or url into $audio :)

Edit - try:

`<?php
$audio = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_audio_embed', true);
if (strstr($audio, '<iframe')) {
echo $audio;
} else {
echo wp_oembed_get( $audio );
}
?>`

Comment: Great thanks so much! How would I get the url/audio embed code into $audio ? :-)

Comment: Try the edit. Let me know if that works for you. (I was a little tired when I answered the first time :)

Comment: Works great - thank you for coming back and showing me the other part too! :)

Comment: No problemo! I realized that the answer was simple enough, and I should have given it completely the first time!